# Transform pandas dataframe to nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below. My question is transforming this into a nested JSON structure like below.

| class | code | hasAttribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | ABC | Y |
| XYZ | BCD | N |
| XYY | CDE | Y |

```
[
  {
    "class": 'XYZ',
    "series": [
      {
        'Code': 'ABC',
        'hasAttribute': 'Y'
      }, 
      {
        'Code': 'BCD',
        'hasAttribute': 'N'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "class": 'XYY',
    "series": [
      {
        'Code': 'CDE',
        'hasAttribute': 'Y'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here series consists of 'Code' and 'hasAttribute' so each code has either 'Y' or 'N' attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and then use `to_dict` to form each group accordingly:

```
lst = df.groupby('class').apply(lambda x: {'class': x['class'].unique()[0], 'series': x.drop('class', axis=1).to_dict('records')}).tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
[
  {
    'class': 'XYY',
    'series': [
      {
        'Code': 'CDE',
        'hasAttribute': 'Y'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'class': 'XYZ',
    'series': [
      {
        'Code': 'ABC',
        'hasAttribute': 'Y'
      },
      {
        'Code': 'BCD',
        'hasAttribute': 'N'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```